# Check if response to prompt is a certain String

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if the user enters a string and verifying it whether the entered string is right or wrong.

Here I have done so far by using JavaScript by using prompt().

I am successful in displaying the prompt message and when I enter any name, it doesn't show anything. I am unable to get the required output.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myText = prompt("Hello World");
  var response;

  if (myText.search(charIn) > 0) {

    response = "Yes, that letter is in the string";

  } else {

    response = "No good, that letter is NOT in the string";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response;

}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: How is the code not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to assign the prompt value to the variable `charIn` and ***Hello World*** to `myText`.

Also it is better to use `includes()`.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myText = 'Hello World'
  var charIn = prompt();
  var response;

  if (myText.includes(charIn)){
    response = "Yes, that letter is in the string";
  }else{    
    response = "No good, that letter is NOT in the string";
  }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response;
}  
   
myFunction();
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: When i am entering the string Hello World, It is showing me the error. Can you help me out with this.

Comment: @EdgyAffairs, in that case condition should be `if (myText.includes(charIn)){`

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: @EdgyAffairs, glad to help. May I request you to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.........thanks

Comment: Yeah I  changed it now